# Replace String only between two keywords

Tags: awk, sed

i have an xml file 
i'm searching in the file all `href`s between `<autor> ... </autor>` and replace them with `authref`

for this i tried with

```
awk '/<autor>/,/<\/autor>/ {gsub(/href/,"authref");}{print;}'
```

this command replaces the hrefs in the complete document, and not only beweet the to keywords / tags.
What i'm doing wrong?

example for an impout txt:

```html
...<autor><autor_Name>name of the autor</autor_Name><autor_infos>some more text</autor_infos><Bild href_fmt="pic/autor.jpg" </Bild>         <Fotocredit>credit infos</Fotocredit></autor>..
```

output:

```html
...<autor><autor_Name>name of the autor</autor_Name><autor_infos>some more text</autor_infos><Bild authref_fmt="pic/autor.jpg" </Bild><Fotocredit>credit infos</Fotocredit></autor>..
```

**Changed part: "href" to "authref"**
but all the other href in the rest of the document should not be changed.

**Update:**
one solution with sed:

```
 sed -e '/<autor>/,/<\/autor>/s/href/authref/'
```

Comment: Why use `awk` to process XML? You can't use a more syntax aware parser like `xmllint` or `xmlstartlet`?

Comment: i have build a long string with sed / awk. and now i have only to made "one more " change. The original script is 5 years old and i don't wont to rewrite it.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: [edit] your example to show hrefs inside AND outside of the target area and also include at least 2 target blocks with hrefs inside and between them to test that a proposed solution doesn't just change hrefs from the first `<autor>` to the last `</autor>` in the file, assuming that'd be undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/<autor>/,/<\/autor>/` doesn't mean from the word `<autor>` to the word `</autor>`, instead it means from **the line containing** the word `<autor>` to **the line containing** the word `</autor>`. Your input is all on 1 line so therefore your replacement occurs across the whole of the input.

Never use range expressions anyway as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions for anything more interesting.

In this case with GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT it'd be something like (untested since the provided example isn't adequate to fully test against):

```
awk -v RS='</?autor>' '!(NR%2){gsub(/href/,"authref")} {ORS=RT} 1' file
```

That assumes there's always matched pairs of `<autor>...</autor>` and they cannot be nested (`<autor>...<autor>...</autor>...</autor>`) and that they don't appear in contexts other than the desired XML tags (e.g. they don't appear within strings or comments).

Answer (score 2):

**Awk** replaces **sed** possibly dual "address" semantics with a *single* "pattern" semantic.  Here is the **sed** equivalent to what you are doing:

```
sed '/<autor>/,/<\/autor>/ s/href/authref/g'
```

Here is the **awk** version:

```
awk -v on=0 '
    /<autor>/   { on = 1 }
    on { gsub(/href/, "authref") }
    /<\/autor>/ { on = 0 }
    1'
```

Note that both of these should be considered quick hacks... neither **sed** nor **awk** solutions are guaranteed to work perfectly with HTML/XML.  It is better to use a tool that properly supports XML parsing for doing this kind of work.  Another way to go about this is to use `xml2 | script | 2xml` preprocessing/postprocessing pipeline to provide a nice flat file format for line-based processors to work in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with awk and sed are that they are **line-oriented**, so they will match *lines* containing `<autor>` and replace "href" **everywhere** in the line, not restricted to within the autor tag.

Your `Bild` tag does not have a closing bracket. Using an XML parser would have pointed that out to you.

```
$ xmlstarlet val file.xml
file.xml - invalid
```

After fixing it:

```
$ xmlstarlet val file.xml
file.xml - valid
$ xmlstarlet edit --rename '//autor/Bild/@href_fmt' --value authref_fmt file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <autor>
    <autor_Name>name of the autor</autor_Name>
    <autor_infos>some more text</autor_infos>
    <Bild authref_fmt="pic/autor.jpg"/>
    <Fotocredit>credit infos</Fotocredit>
  </autor>
</root>
```

To preserve your input format, use `xmlstarlet edit -O -P ...`
To write the output back to the file, use `xmlstarlet edit -L ...`

Comment: awk is record-oriented, not line-oriented. It just reads a line as a record by default.